# CALCULATE function results in missing monthly values but correct Totals

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I need some help with a DAX formula.
I am trying to perform a simple calculation that is based on a slicer selection.

```
ActualsReleased= CALCULATE(SUM('reporting  
ActualsProducedReleased'[ActualsReleasedWX]),FILTER('reporting  
Time','reporting Time'[DateId]<=SELECTEDVALUE([Version date])))
```

My problem is that the calculation works fine for the Yearly total but it doesn't allow me to display it in months in a Matrix visualization.
The relationship between the 'reporting Time' and 'reporting ActualsProducedReleased' table is defined on a date dimension that is present in both tables.

I pulled in Year and Month columns from my Time table but it is not possible to drill down to months. Furthermore, I can see that the calculation produces the desired results but it doesn't want to display them according to the Time dimensions.

In this example I have selected 31/03/2023 as the Version date and it shows me data for 2023 only, while the Total is displaying correctly that I have released 3750,4 since 2017.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amat6.png)

So why am I seeing data only for 2023?

Comment: This is basically a life to date calculation (kind of like a YTD calculation, but it doesn't reset each year). One way to do this would be to add a column to your calendar table that calculates the first of the month for each date. Then you can use that date on your X-axis, and it will sort. (or you could use it to sort another column).

Comment: That doesn't explain why I don't see any values for years before 2023.